# Не работает логика на switch

Tags: c++

друзья. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе первой буквы месяца - выводилось полное название месяца. Я написал код. Но мой код не работает. Подскажите, почему?

```
int c;
    cout << "Введите первую букву месяца: ";
    cin >> c;
    switch(c) {
     case 'О':
       cout << "Октябрь" << endl;
       break;
    default:
       break;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: Возможно у `c` стоит сделать тип `char`?
Тогда и `cin` перестанет его читать как `int`

Comment: Поменял тип на char - по прежнему не работает. Ввожу букву - не выводит месяц, а просто завершает работу

Answer (score 3):

Установите локаль и посмотрите кодировку:

```
# include <locale>
int main(){
  char * loc = setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  cout<<"loc = "<<loc<<endl;
  }
```

Например, если в консоли "Russian_Russian.1251" , то и кодировка текста программы должна быть CP1251.

Comment: Посмотрите еще, какая буква О у Вас стоит в тексте программы и какую Вы вводите...